# Spacemacs - What does C-c do (what things are inside this menu)?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I'm learning emacs/spacemacs right now and I'm slightly confused about the `C-c` binding.

Pressing it opens a menu with many helpful things that I cannot reach otherwise (it seems like it at least). I'm also confused what the difference is to `,` which opens the major mode commands.

Here's a concrete example: I'm in org-mode. Using `,` I can access many features that this major mode offers, I can add stuff, manipulate text, and open the agenda. But if I want to, for example, add the current file to the agenda (via `org-agenda-file-to-front`) I have to press `C-c [`. I can't find this command within the major mode bindings in the `,` menu.

Why are some things within `C-c` and some within `,` if they do belong to the same major mode? And what is the purpose of `C-c` in general? What stuff is being put there?

Comment: I don't have spacemacs myself, so I'm not sure what the correct keybinding is, but you can use `C-h k` (`SPC h d k` I think) to find out what's behind `C-c` and use `C-h f` to know what keybinds are bound to `org-agenda-file-to-front`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it expects something to come after `C-c` when I type it in `C-h k`, it's simply waiting for another key to come after so it doesn't want to tell me about `C-c`

Comment: Yeah don't use the `C-h k` but `SPC h d k` (describe-key) if you're using spacemacs. I still have the default keybindings.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the same behavior

Comment: yeah, looks like it, don't worry. The problem is that there's no documentation about it, I would have expected something like "`C-c` is a prefix key used for additional major mode functionality" or whatever it's actually there

Comment: Well one other thing you can try is `C-h m` which describes the major mode you are in. `C-c` shortcuts are mostly major mode dependent so you might find a good overview there.

Comment: I was just googling now too. And it seems `C-c C-h` does the trick

Comment: Oh, that has to be it. `C-c C-h` gives me the title "Major Mode Bindings Starting With `C-c`. So that prefix is actually used for additional major mode functions that didn't fit into the `,` menu or something.

Thank you! This definitely answers the question about what it's there for. Wanna write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really answer on why some keybinding are put under `,` and some under `C-c`.

To know the difference between the two, you can check what bindings they prefix with the shortcut `, C-h` and `C-c C-h`.

Other usefull bindings are:

`C-h m` to show what the current major mode bindings are

`C-h k C-c [` to know what's bound to `C-c [`

`C-h f org-agenda-file-to-front` to know what bindings are bound to that function